# Split last two words in a sentence into two different cells in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Temasek Boulevard, Suntec Tower, (Singapore 0389)**

The above sentence is a address . The last two words is country name (singapore) and zipcode (0389).

How to split country name and zip code in two different cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column containing the addresses. Go to Data > Text to Columns. Select Delimited, then press next and uncheck all of the delimiters. Check the box next to Other and put in a left bracket as the delimiter. Once you've done this, you'll have to repeat the process, using a space as the delimiter to separate the last two values, then use find and replace to remove the last bracket.

Comment: @AnandSelvaraj .. you may make a green tick below the downvote sign if this helped ...